# Best way to redo search like yelp/airbnb on google map v3 api panning (moving-zooming)

Tags: google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am displaying list of places based on certain filter criteria, and place markers on the map for the returned results based on their address.

How can I redo/re-fetch the search results based on map dragged/changed?

https://www.airbnb.com/s/oslo?checkin=&checkout=&guests=1&sw_lat=59.91443825522735&sw_lng=10.693570995384334&ne_lat=59.955568123899354&ne_lng=10.780431652122616&zoom=13&search_by_map=true

http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=dinner&find_loc=new+york&ns=1&ls=c39e25a5fe1312f2

Scenario:

I have list of places within los angles. Since I pass los angles filter parameter to search result query.

Now, Instead of passing the Irvine search parameter from drop down, I move the map to see the Irvine city. Now the search results should be filtered based on map change/panning, and I should be able to pass the Irvine as search parameter.

PS: I know, I can use google map v3 api IDLE event to get the current bounds of the map, and other standard api stuff. However, I am not sure how to use them to implement my listed requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() { alert('map dragged'); } );
```

Everytime the map is dragged you can run whatever function gets the current bounds and plots the markers.

Comment: I would use the `idle` event for this instead of `dragend`. From the doc: 'This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning **or** zooming.'

Comment: Well I suppose that's the other way. I haven't really tested `idle` before. How long counts as idle? If it's as instantaneous as `zoom_changed` and `dragend` then yeah it'd be better.